# Eclipse: starting custom eclipse app under linux returns to the command line prompt instantly

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-pde

I am developing an Eclipse/Equinox based OSGI WebApplication (using embedded Jetty) and using headless PDE-Build for building the app. My build creates a zip file for Linux GTK and one for my local macosx.

This has worked well so far and I could just unzip the linux zip file on my Debian based server and run *./eclipse* from the command line and the app would start up.

Yesterday I had a new build ready and deployed it, unzipped it and started *./eclipse* and nothing happened. No output...nothing. It returned me the command line prompt immediately.

```
christoph@myserver:~/myapp$ ./eclipse 
christoph@myserver:~/myapp$
```

What I have tried afterwards was starting manually with the equinox launcher:

```
christoph@myserver:~/myapp$ java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar
```

This looked much better and the application seemed to start as usual....but after about 10 seconds it stopped in the middle of startup and I was back at the command line prompt.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the reason or how I can debug whats going on with the eclipse startup file? I think I haven't changed anything in the build scripts for weeks and the resulting zip file has the usual size what it was before. I also rebooted the server.

I have tried things like *./eclipse -noexit*, *./eclipse -debug*, *./eclipse -clean* and *./eclipse -refresh* , *./eclipse -vm /path/to/my/jdk/java* but everything has the same effect. No output, nothing.

Thanks
Christoph

Comment: There should be some log file in your eclipse directory. That file will contain the root cause.

Comment: I forgot to mention that: there was no logfile created. I know usually the configuration directory contains logfiles like 1267091477938.log. But when I start with ./eclipse no logfile gets created. When I start with java -jar ... instead, there is a logfile which has information but that is not what I am looking for. I would like to know why ./eclipse isn't working. any other ideas? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This problem has been solved. Scroll to the bottom of this answer for the solution.

Yeah, I think I found it...by coincidence.
I am not yet sure what the root cause is, but I know which symptom causes the startup problems.

Basically I think it is related to race-conditions of my Build-process and the Delta-pack and the following jar file / folders:

**Folder**: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520

vs.

**Jar**: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519.jar

The spot which I stumbled upon were a few messages during the build which I saw a lot, but never really thought about:
E.g.

> [java] [eclipse.generateFeature]
>   Bundle
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86:
>        [java] [eclipse.generateFeature]     Another singleton version selected:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520

This sounds like the build processed picked *something else*...?!? Which seems odd to me.

In the case where it *was working* this jar file was extracted (so that it was a folder with the name *org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520*) and this folder contained a file called *eclipse_1206.so*.

In the case where it was *not working* there was also a folder with the name *org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520* but the file *eclipse_1206.so* was *NOT* in this folder.

I also verified that on my local Ubuntu machine and which gave me some more output in the *not working case* than the Debian machine.

When it was not working under Ubuntu I got something like this:

> $ ./eclipse
>
> (.:26981): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   invalid (NULL) pointer instance
>
> (.:26981): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **:
>   g_signal_connect_data: assertion
>   `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)'
>   failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (.:26981): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **:
>   g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed
>
> (.:26981): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   value "TRUE" of type `gboolean' is
>   invalid or out of range for property`
>   visible' of type `gboolean'
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (.:26981): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **:
>   g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for
>   GtkWindow not set; you must always set
>   a screen for a GtkWindow before using
>   the window
>
> (.:26981): Gdk-CRITICAL **:
>   gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen:
>   assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
>   failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_context_set_font_description:
>   assertion `context != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion
>   `context != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_context_set_language: assertion
>   `context != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_new: assertion `context
>   != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_text: assertion
>   `layout != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion
>   `layout != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion
>   `layout != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion
>   `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode:
>   assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)'
>   failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_set_width: assertion
>   `layout != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Pango-CRITICAL **:
>   pango_layout_get_extents: assertion
>   `layout != NULL' failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen:
>   assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'
>   failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings:
>   assertion `GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)'
>   failed
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid
>   icon size 6
>
> (.:26981): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion
>   `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)'
>   failed Segmentation fault

On a hosted Debian machine (vserver.de) I got *NO* output as described in my opening question above.

Probably during the build process sometimes the former and sometimes the latter was used. I cannot explain why at the moment. I also notice that the folder is for the plain _x86 (32bit) architecture, while the jar is for the x86_64 (64bit) architecture. Not sure why the 64 is picked at all, because I didn't specify x86_64 in my build.properties.

Also what I don't understand is the fact that the resulting folder with the name *org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520* contained the file *eclipse_1206.so*, even though this file is ONLY present in the *org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519.jar* (note the ...x86_64...)

**Conclusion**
I think the root cause is, that I have some kind of inconsistent / broken / messed up targetplatform or delta-pack. Maybe I am also doing something wrong the way how I do the headless PDE build, but I could not tell so far because it seemed to work...sometimes...and sometimes not :)

I verified my statement above by exchanging the accordant folder with the one which contained the *eclipse_1206.so* file and suddenly it worked. Reproducible.
So, if you have similar startup problems under Linux, maybe check for the existence of the *eclipse_1206.so* in the equinox launcher folder / jar (e.g. org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520)

In the meantime I will investigate what the root cause was and how to setup the build properly and will write that down in a blog post.

Thanks to everybody trying to help out so far.

Christoph

**Update Solution:**
The solution was to download a fresh Eclipse Deltapack for the 3.5 version and replace all my ..launcher.. plugins in my target platform with the fresh ones. The problem was a corrupt launcher plugin which had the *eclipse_1206.so* file missing.

Update 2010/03/01: On another note,I found out that SVN by default ignores the file extension .so which was also a source of my problems. 
My solution I described above was only working locally so far which was correct.
But today I wanted to check if the builds comming out of my build server are also correct finally and surprise..they were still broken. I instantly checked the launcher plugin folder and see..the eclipse_1206.so was missing again. Then I checked the SVN repository and really the file wasn't there. It turnes out that SVN ignores those files by default which I now have described here: [SVN ingnores .so files by default](http://www.dzone.com/links/svn_ignores_file_extension_so_by_default_which_co.html)

Comment: Ok, it becomes pretty clear now. The reason was a messed up targetplatform, most likely from earlier days when I was setting up the build and doing my first steps with a headless PDE build. I might have modified the launcher jar myself and accidentally removed the *eclipse_1206.so* file. I think I remember having difficulties before with the unpack-option for plugins inside the feature.xml or so. I have just downloaded the latest delta-pack for Eclipse 3.5 and verified the content. eclipse_1206.so is there. Now the build works reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no log file produced, it can be due to a faulty `eclipse.ini` (like extra spaces at then end of one of the lines of `eclipse.ini` content)

Did that `.ini` file somehow changed recently?
(Or refer a path which is no longer available on the deployment server where you see this issue?)

Comment: I had a look but I cannot see anything obvious. It gets more confusing. The same build starts up under ubuntu, but not under Debian any more. But an earlier revision was running fine under Debian the last 2 weeks. Damn, this seems to be a hard nut to crack. I would like to find out in which direction to investigate. Is it the OS, is it the build process, is it the JVM? Ok I will go on. Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: Correction: I was wrong: the same build doesn't start under ubuntu.

Comment: @Christoph: did you try using your own eclipse.ini, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590 ?